# Cannot resolve symbol 'name' in pattern-matching switch expressions

Tags: pattern-matching, java-19

when I use the word "var" the IDE gives me an error:

> Error:Cannot resolve symbol 'var'
> ',' or ')' expected
> Cannot resolve symbol 'name'

The code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class hello {
    sealed interface ToGreet {};
    record User(String name) implements ToGreet {};
    record World() implements ToGreet {};

    public static void main(String... args) {
        switch (args.length > 0 ? new User(args[0]) : new World()) {
            case User(var name) -> out.println("Hello " + name);
            case World w -> out.println("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

So why does it happen? How can I solve it?

The pics:

[image: Problems]
[image: Settings]
[image: Structure]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are getting this particular error message. The actual reason the code doesn't compile is different.

The type of the conditional expression `args.length > 0 ? new User(args[0]) : new World()` is `Object`. As a result, you should be getting an error saying that `An enhanced switch statement should be exhaustive; a default label expected`.

The compiler doesn't infer that this expression always produces a `ToGreet` instance, so it's not sufficient to specify cases for the two possible implementations of this sealed interface.

The are several options to fix the error.

Use an intermediate `ToGreet` variable to assign the conditional expression to:

```
ToGreet greet = args.length > 0 ? new User(args[0]) : new World();
switch (greet) {
    case User(var name) -> out.println("Hello " + name);
    case World w -> out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

Add a default label:

```
switch (args.length > 0 ? new User(args[0]) : new World()) {
    case User(var name) -> out.println("Hello " + name);
    case World w -> out.println("Hello World!");
    default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
}
```

Add a case for `Object`:

```
switch (args.length > 0 ? new User(args[0]) : new World()) {
    case User(var name) -> out.println("Hello " + name);
    case World w -> out.println("Hello World!");
    case Object o -> throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
}
```